# Bootstrap 3 drop-down on input

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap's drop-down menu for an text input element.

It's working fine until I try to use it in an input-group. Then the offset gets messed up and the menu is displayed over the text input.

Anyone has an idea on how to fix this?

[image: Wrong an correct]

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Wrong:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="dropdown open">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>One</li>
                            <li>Two</li>
                            <li>Three</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Load</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">...</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Correct:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <div class="dropdown open">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>One</li>
                            <li>Two</li>
                            <li>Three</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: set `top: 34px;` by targeting it form class or remove float form `input`

Comment: remove `float:left` from `input`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Remove `float:left`; from `.input-group .form-control` or add `float:none;` on`.input-group .form-control`

Comment: @Conny Olsson You can accept the answer if is this helpful for you..

Answer (score 1):

Just add input-group-btn class to that below div.

```
<div class="input-group-btn dropdown open">
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
 .input-group-btn {
 
      width: 100%;
 }
</style>
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Wrong:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-btn dropdown open">                 <input type="text" class="form-control">

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>One</li>
                            <li>Two</li>
                            <li>Three</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Load</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">...</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Correct:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <div class="dropdown open">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>One</li>
                            <li>Two</li>
                            <li>Three</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but then the input-group doesn't has the full width.

Comment: Oh yeah @ConnyOlsson, I have updated the answer to set width of input-btn-group  to 100%

Answer (score 0):

This is because the .input-group .form-control gets a "float: left". You need to disable it.

For example you could change

```
<input type="text" class="form-control">
```

to

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" style="float: none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
<select class="dropdown-menu">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>tree</option>
</select>
```

instead of

```
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li>One</li>
       <li>Two</li>
       <li>Three</li>
  </ul>
```

now you have to put the first select field with css under your input field

Comment: I have to use UL for different reasons, but thanks!